# Random projection a fixing vector is equivalent to projecting a random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, geometry, rotations, projective-geometry

In the book Vershynin the following exercise is presented:

Let $P$ be a projection in $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto a random $m$-dimensional subspace $E \sim \mbox{Unif}(G_{n,m})$, where $G_{n,m}$ is the Grassmanian, the set of $m$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $Q$ be a $m \times n$ matrix obtained by choosing the first $m$ rows of a random $n \times n$ matrix $\sim \mbox{Unif}( O(n) )$, namely drawn uniformly from the orthogonal group.

(a) show that for any fixed point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\| P x \|_2$ and $\|Q x\|_2$ have the same distribution,

(b) show that, for any fixed point $z \in \mathbb{S}^{m-1}$,
$$
Q^T z \sim \mbox{Unif} ( \mathbb{S}^{n-1}),
$$
where $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the $n-1$ dimensional unit sphere and here *Unif* means uniform distribution in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

I think that one should use the singular value decomposition for $P$ and make use of the rotational invariance but I am not able to figure our how. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061071/random-projection-of-a-fixed-point?rq=1

Comment: Two answers are good! But I wonder why we can assume $P$ is orthogonal projection instead of ordinary projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of $Q$ provides a (fairly) concrete realization of a uniformly distributed random Grassmanian and the associated orthogonal projection $P$.

More precisely, let ${\cal L}_n={\rm Unif} (O(n))$ be the law of uniformly distributed orthogonal $n\times n$-matrices. This law is by definition (Fact 1) right and left-invariant under multiplication by any $R\in O(n)$.
If $U\sim {\cal L}_n$ then also  $RU\sim {\cal L}_n$ and $UR\sim {\cal L}_n$.

Let $\pi=\pi_{m,n} \in M_{m,n}$ be the matrix selecting the $m$ first rows.
Then (Fact 2) the law of $Q=\pi_{m,n} U$ is also
invariant under  right-multiplication by $R_n\in O(n)$. [In fact it is also invariant under left-multiplication by $S_m\in O(m)$ but this is not needed here].

Now, if $z\in {\Bbb R}^m$ is a unit vector, then so is $Q^t z$ (since $Q Q^t=\pi \pi^t={\bf 1}_m$) and  by Fact 2 its distribution is the same as that of $R_n^t Q^t z$ for any $R_n\in O(n)$. Thus $Q^t z$ must be uniformly distributed in $S^{n-1}$.

The image  $E=Q^t ({\Bbb R}^m)$ is a random $m$-dimensional subspace again uniformly distributed as required and $P=Q^t Q$ provides the realization of the abstract orthogonal projection onto $E$. Then for every $x\in {\Bbb R}^n$:
$$ \|Px \|_2 = \|Q^t Q x\|_2 = \|Q x\|_2.$$
So the above norms will follow the same law.

Answer (score 2):

For (a), one approach is to show that the distribution of $\|Px\|_2$ where $P$ is *random* and $x$ is *fixed* is the same as the distribution of $\|Px\|_2$ when $P$ is *fixed* and $x$ is *random*. All this really uses is rotational invariance (i.e., invariance under orthonormal changes of basis).

Formally, we proceed as follows: Let $S\in O(n)$ be fixed, and let $P$ be drawn randomly from the Grassmanian manifold $G_{n,m}$. Because multiplication by $S$ is an orthonormal change of basis and the Grassmanian does not depend on choice of basis,  $P\sim S^\top P S$. Because this is true for any fixed $S$, if we take $T\sim \mathrm{Unif}(O(n))$, then $P\sim T^\top P T$ as well. So
$$ \|Px\|_2\sim \|T^\top PT x\|_2 = (PTx)^\top TT^\top (P T x) = \|PTx\|_2. $$
Let $y = Tx$. I claim $\|Py\|_2\sim\|\pi y\|_2$ for any *fixed* $P\in G_{n,m}$, where $\pi\in G_{n,m}$ is the projection onto the first $m$ coordinates. Since $P$ is a projection, it has singular value decomposition $P =  S^\top\pi S$ for $S\in O(n)$. It follows that $\|Py\|_2=\|\pi S y\|_2\sim\|\pi y\|_2$, where we use the fact that $S T \sim T$ because $\mathrm{Unif}(O(n))$ is invariant under orthonormal changes of basis. To finish, observe that we can write $Q = \pi T$, so $Qx\sim \pi Tx = \pi y$.

For (b), we have $Q^\top z\sim (QT)^\top z = T^\top (Q^\top z)$, for $T\sim\mathrm{Unif}(O(n))$, using similar reasoning as above.

Comment: could you clarify why P has a principal value decomposition since it is a projection and why we can conclude that the two matrices of the principal value decomposition are one the transpose of the other one? Thanks

Comment: When you write that P is drawn from G_nm do you mean that P is a projection on a subspace E which is drawn uniformly from G_nm?

Comment: Here is a bit more detail on the SVD of P: Because P is an orthogonal projection, it is positive semidefinite. This means it has an SVD of the form S^T Sigma S, where Sigma is the diagonal matrix of singular values. Next, its eigenvalues are 0 and 1, as its minimal polynomial is x*(1-x). Finally, P has rank m, so its singular values are 1 with multiplicity m and 0 with multiplicity n-m. Hence we can take Sigma = pi.

Comment: And for your second question, yes, P and pi in my answer should really be projection maps onto elements in G_nm.

Comment: If P is an orthogonal projection, then the argument is perfect. But can $P$ be an projection matrix without assuming $P^T=P$?